# UFT: How to create a list of descriptive objects in a library and use it in another library

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft14

I want to pass a list of object names with properties from an excel file to the DataTable and create descriptive objects in a library of UFT.

After that, I want to use these objects in another library, to perform operations on them.

Issue:

1. I am able to pass the object names and properties through excel file and create objects. But, I want to know that how can I use the objects created in another library.
2. Is there a way that I can store these objects in a list (eg: Data dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

You can store the objects in a Global Variable be it an array or Dictionary. For your scope I would chose a dictionary